# C# - How to get the right line number in error message when validating XML using XmlSchemaSet?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xmlschemaset

So I am trying to validate a xml file against a xsd file using XmlSchemaSet and I tried implementing the following [solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6487cb4-cff4-40ed-b303-5f430e18bd58/how-to-get-all-xml-schema-validation-errors-with-xmlreadercreate-or-otherwise?forum=xmlandnetfx) in my project and it finds all the errors in the xml file but the line number it gets is always 1 for some reason. Here is the code that deals with the issue:

xmlValidate class:

```
public class xmlValidate
{
    private IList<string> allValidationErrors = new List<string>();

    public IList<string> AllValidationErrors
    {
        get
        {
            return this.allValidationErrors;
        }
    }

    public void checkForErrors(object sender, ValidationEventArgs error)
    {
        if (error.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error || error.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
        {
            this.allValidationErrors.Add(String.Format("<br/>" + "Line: {0}: {1}", error.Exception.LineNumber, error.Exception.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

Main function:

```
public string validate(string xmlUrl, string xsdUrl)
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(xmlUrl);
        xml.Schemas.Add(null, xsdUrl);

        string xmlString = xml.OuterXml;
        XmlSchemaSet xmlSchema = new XmlSchemaSet();
        xmlSchema.Add(null, xsdUrl); 

        if (xmlSchema == null)
        {
            return "No Schema found at the given url."; 
        }

        string errors = "";
        xmlValidate handler = new xmlValidate();
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.CloseInput = true;
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(handler.checkForErrors);
        settings.Schemas.Add(xmlSchema);
        settings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema 
                                 | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation 
                                 | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings 
                                 | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints;
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlString); 

        using (XmlReader vr = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings))
        {
            while (vr.Read()) { }
        }

        if (handler.AllValidationErrors.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (String errorMessage in handler.AllValidationErrors)
            {
                errors += errorMessage; 
            }
            return errors; 
        }

        return "No Errors!"; 
   }
```

Does anyone see my issue? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be, that you load your XML without formatting?
Try with `XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument { PreserveWhitespace = true }`

I guess that could be important for getting the right line number but I did not check to be honest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm getting an error stating that `preserveWhiteSpace` does not exist in the current context. Where does this variable come from?

Comment: sorry copy/paste error from my code-base. it should just be 'true'. I edited my answer.

Comment: Ahh it seems that all I had to do was set `xml.PreserveWhitespace = true`. Thank you man I would have never guessed that! I'd upvote you but I guess I'm not allowed yet lol. Thanks again.

Comment: glad I could help!